# Can anyone explain the below code.What is the line which calculates no of pages in document

Tags: javascript

```
var x=window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
for (var i in x)
{
    var z=x[i].split('=',2);
    vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);
}
var x=['frompage','topage','page'];
for (var i in x)
{
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
    for (var j=0; j<y.length; ++j)
        y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
}
```

Basically our application is using **wkhtmltopdf** utility, and we want to modify this code so that header is not included on the last page of pdf. please suggest.

Comment: Please put your question in the text of the post, not only in the title. Anyhow, the answer is probably `y.length`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've given enough information; however here's what the code is doing. The first part takes the web page address and everything after the "?" part (the query, or search string) and then takes the `foo=bar&baz=boo` style pairs, splitting them into object `vars`, as key/value pairs, URL-unescaped.

The next part looks for HTML elements with class names `frompage`, `topage` and `page`. For every one found, it sets the text content of those elements to the value of variables extracted from the URL with the same name - e.g. the URL might say `...?frompage=1,topage=3,page=2`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent

There's nothing I can really see in the code snippet you provide that indicates whether these HTML elements might be a part of a header or footer, or indicate the total number of pages so you could detect when the last page had been reached in the generated PDF and skip the header output.

Comment: (In short unless you're lucky enough to find someone here with in-depth knowledge of the JavaScript inner workings of "wkhtmltopdf", I fear you will have to delve deeper to solve your problem, and/or post wider sections of code than just the snippet above).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Basically our application invokes wkhtmltopdf which in turn converts the generated output html file to PDF. Now issue is I need to put a unique id on all pages except the last page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var x = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
for (var i in x)
{
    var z = x[i].split('=',2);
    vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);
}

var x = ['frompage','topage','page'];
for (var i in x)
{
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
    for (var j=0; j < y.length; ++j){
        y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];

        // if current page equals total pages  
        if (vars[x[2]] == vars[x[1]]) { 
            // replace "FakeHeaders" with id of your table in which header is getting displayed
            document.getElementById("FakeHeaders").style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does remove last page printing

Comment: If this code is working please dont forget to mark it as answer